# error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier in VS2012, but not Mac

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

The following function gives me an `undeclared identifier` error.

Note the variable `i` declared in the middle of the function (line 8):

```
int
mb_convert_to_offsets( MemBuf *mb)
{
    _check( mb);
    if (mb->size != sizeof( intptr_t))
        return eInvalid;
    intptr_t *tb = (intptr_t*)mb->data;
    int i;
    char *s, *s0 = (char *)(tb + mb->n);
    for (i = 0; i < mb->n; i++) {
        s = (char *)tb[i];
...
```

However, if I declare the variable at the first of the method I have no error:

```
int
mb_convert_to_offsets( MemBuf *mb)
{
    int i;
    _check( mb);
    if (mb->size != sizeof( intptr_t))
        return eInvalid;
    intptr_t *tb = (intptr_t*)mb->data;
    char *s, *s0 = (char *)(tb + mb->n);
    for (i = 0; i < mb->n; i++) {
        s = (char *)tb[i];
...
```

I have read that [C99 and C11 standards in VS2012 are not a priority](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776395/c-compiler-support-for-declarations-in-the-middle-of-the-block-c99) for Microsoft right now.

However, I am converting a bunch of code that is coming over from a Mac where this code style is prevalent and I'd rather not have to refactor it all.

Are there any workarounds in code, or some settings in Visual Studio that would allow the declaration of variables in the middle of the function?

Comment: C **or** C++? It does make a difference.

Comment: C, I have edited the tags

Comment: Is this c or c++?  Because MSVC will compile the above fine as a cpp file.  Implicit conversion to/frpm `void*` may cause you problems, but...

Comment: There **are** compilers that support C99 and run on/generate code for Windows. Try MinGW and GCC, for example.

Comment: @H2CO3 Help me understand why the /tp switch was so bad.

Comment: @Yakk I *am* having problems with `void*`.  I'm having to cast everything `void*` to `char*` explicitly.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: You'd be best off getting a real C compiler for Windows

Comment: @paqogomez Because you have C code. C code should be compiled with a C compiler, and not with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although some work, but quiet straight forward would be to add a fresh context where definitions appear in the middle of an existing context.

So your snippet would look like this then:

```
int
mb_convert_to_offsets( MemBuf *mb)
{
  _check( mb);
  if (mb->size != sizeof( intptr_t))
    return eInvalid;
  { /* addition */
    intptr_t *tb = (intptr_t*)mb->data;
    int i;
    char *s, *s0 = (char *)(tb + mb->n);
    for (i = 0; i < mb->n; i++) 
    {
      s = (char *)tb[i];

      ...

    }

    ...
  } /* addition */
```

Such modifications can safely be considered cosmetic.

Comment: Was it you that answered with the /tp switch that got downvoted so quickly?

Comment: @paqogomez: Err, no that hadn't been me. Why?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was.  I tried that solution and it worked.  Wanted to understand better why it was so verboten.

Comment: As for yours, if I have to modify each function's scope, its probably just as easy to move the declarations to the top.  Tho, there maybe special cases where this would be more useful.

Comment: @paqogomez: Shifting around defintions of variables might easily break the code('s logic), especially if initialisations are involoved. This definitly can't happen by "just" putting certain lines of code into a seperate context.